# Is it possible to write VBA macros that auto corrects spellings in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I found macros to find words misspelled but Is it possible to write VBA macros that auto corrects spellings in excel? I am new to VBA.

Comment: You might be able to call spellcheck on a certain cell.  If so, you could call it from the cell change event and analyse the cell value and make decisions on what to do.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554567/automatically-replace-misspellings-with-suggestions-for-long-lists-of-terms

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Spell()
    Dim xlRng As Range
    Set xlRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    xlRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Select
    Cells.CheckSpelling SpellLang:=1033

    Set xlRng = Nothing
End Sub
```